# Problems with the electric field study on cylindrical symmetry surfaces using Gauss's Law

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

I was exploring cases of Gauss's Law application on different surfaces in the Professor Moyses Nussenzveig book (Basic Physics Course, Vol.III) and I'm having a hard time understanding completely a specific example. Basically, there is a coaxial cable formed by a cylindrical shell of length $L$, inner radius $r1$ and outer radius $r2$. The shell has a charge $q>0 $ and the central wire has a charge $ q <0 $. I would like to find the charge densities on the inner and outer surfaces, as well as the electric field as a function of the cylinder radius.

I initially thought of finding $ \vec E $ through integration, considering $\vec E $//$ \vec n $

$$\int_S\vec{\mathbf{E}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}dA=E(2\pi rL)+0+0=2\pi rLE$$

I also know that $q_{\mathrm{enc}}=\lambda_{\mathrm{enc}}L$, because $q_{\mathrm{enc}}$ of Gauss’s law is directly proportional to L.

So, i found the field for $r <r1 =$ $\frac {-\lambda}{2πr\epsilon0}$ and for $ r1<r<r2$ = $0$.

However, I have doubts on how I should find the field for $ r> r2 $, since there is a charge on the shell's outer surface. Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe it would help if you corrected a few things.  First notice that your equation is not dimensionaly consistent.   Actually ... if you correct that you may see what else you have to do to make progress.  Think about that for a while.

Comment: @garyp Did something change in the question? The equations seem dimensionally consistent to me, am I missing something?

Comment: @Philip Maybe I'm misreading it?  It looks like E times area on the left, and E times length on the right.

Comment: @garyp There's an $r$ on the right as well, too, right? So it's $E\times r\times L$?

Comment: The integral that I solved represents the flux through the cylindrical shell part. I also know that $\lambda_{\mathrm{enc}}=\frac{\sigma_02\pi RL}{L}=2\pi R\sigma_0$ considering that the ponit its outside the shell (it was what I understood). So, i think that $\vec E =$ $\frac{2\pi R\sigma_0}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r}\hat{\mathbf{r}}=\frac{R\sigma_0}{\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r}\hat{\mathbf{r}}$, where $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ is a unit vector, perpendicular to the axis. However I'm not sure about how to proceed with the problem.

Comment: @garyp I progressed a little more in the problem, thanks!

Comment: @Philip Check.  I need new glasses.